# IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate and relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate is meant to help write code that works the same whether the database is empty or populated.  But linking objects needs different code.  When the database is empty, objects don't have IDs yet and you link them by assigning the navigational property.  When the objects already exist, however, navigational properties don't work and you need to set the foreign keys directly.  <del>Navigational properties do work for proxies in both cases, at the cost of forfeiting POCOs.</del> Edit: Actually, proxies don't work when both entities are old.

This sample crashes in the second SaveChanges call, when EF tries to set CountryID to 0:

```
public class Country
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual int CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Foo()
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            //var c = new Country();
            var c = db.Country.Create();
            c.Name = "usa";
            db.Country.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, c);

            //var p = new Person();
            var p = db.Person.Create();
            p.Name = "billg";
            p.Country = c;
            db.Person.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, p);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());
        Foo();
        Foo();
    }
}
```

How is AddOrUpdate used?

Comment: I highly recommend you to read it http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate is meant to help write code that works the same whether the database is empty or populated.

`AddOrUpdate` is meant to be used only in `Seed` method of code first migrations. It is not supposed to be used in normal code because it has big overhead and some limitations. Overhead is additional query to database and reflection. Limitation is that it checks only the main entity you are passing but not its relations. Each relation is supposed to be handled by separate call to `AddOrUpdate`:

```
static void Foo()
{
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        var c = new Country() {Name = "abc"};
        db.Country.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, c);

        var p = new Person()
        {
            Name = "me",
            CountryID = c.ID,
            Country = c 
        };

        db.Person.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, p);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I shortened my code to paste it here.  My application only uses AddOrUpdate in an DbMigrationsConfiguration.Seed override.

Your sample works, but i feel uneasy about assigning both Country and CountryID.  Do you recommend always assigning both?  My application uses composite keys and it's easier, clearer and less error prone to assign just the navigational property.

Comment: @BrunoMartinez AddOrUpdate ***will not*** set the foreign key values that the Navigation Property (and database) relies on - even if that entity has already been 'added or updated' or queried-for directly (and EF should be able to fix-up the relationship). Realistically, ***you only need to set the FK***, unless you need to navigate the relationships later in the seed. Further, if you want to use the relationship as part of the `identifierExpression` you must use the FK Id as it must be a primitive or enum value and the property mapped to a column - other entities cannot be used.

Comment: RE: *"it's easier, clearer and less error prone to assign just the navigational property."* I would advise adding some extension methods for your entities to `AddRelatedEntity(RelatedEntity entity){..}` or just use the native `DbSet` methods to basically write your own `AddOrUpdate()`. It *is* frustrating that this API surface doesn't follow the same conventions as the rest of the DbContext/DbSet operations. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯